# No Internet on Advanced Tomato router - Please advise

Tags: router, internet, tomato

I got a new R7000 router, it worked fine on stock netgear firmware. I decided to flash it with advanced tomato 3.5-140. 
Flashed and installed fine, I followed all the instructions. 
However I can't get it to connect to the internet?! I've changed the basic settings to PPPoe as that is what my connection uses, still didnt work. I've tried reseting to default, erase nvram, hard reset and even reset the modem a few times. But still nothing has worked. 
I am totally at a loss with this. I've had many routers over the years and not had an issue like this. What am I missing??
I've googled this problem but can't find an answer, seems a reset fixed it for most.

Please help

Comment: What works on it? Sounds like you can connect to it through a lan port, can lan devices communicate with each other? Does everything else work 100%, except no internet?

Comment: yeah I can connect to the router and access the settings but on the status page there is no internet connection showing and I have the exclamation mark showing for no connection on the pc. I've not tried communicating with other lan devices as theres nothing for me to access anyway as they are not devices with hdd or anything. 
I can't figure out why its not detecting an internet connection. I setup my PPPoe connection with the login details. By default it was set to DHCP. The internet didnt work on either. On the stock firmware it connects fine.

Comment: At least being able to ping other lan devices would confirm it can use the ports & some things work ok. So the router's not getting an IP address or something, can it ping any sites at all, your isp's dns servers, or 8.8.8.8 (google?). Maybe connecting to it directly (ssh/telnet) would let you ping & check `route` in case the web interface is out. Maybe just trying another version or build of Tomato might change something, you've definitely got the right one? Or maybe your isp just has some settings you're missing, could ask them? You're paying them after all

Comment: I'm not getting a WAN IP, so pinging anything is useless as the router isnt connecting to the internet even the though the modem and line are active. 
Must be some setting but I can't figure it out.

Comment: can anyone else shed some light on this problem? I still haven't resolved this.